# Multiple condition in decode function to insert value in table

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert, decode

I have the below trigger in which i want to insert value in the `FIELD_TRACKING` table.
I have `FIELD_TRACKING_COMMENTS` field in which i want to insert value based on condition. The condition is if `(Last_Updated_By = 115 and new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,N)` then the comment should be `This KPI has been deactivated by System -> Active Alerts`. I already put a condition in decode statement `decode(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,'N','This KPI has been deactivated by System -> Active Alerts','' ))` for `FIELD_TRACKING_COMMENTS` field and its working fine. But i want to add additional conditional `'Last_Updated_By = 115'` and i dont know how to add it in decode statement.

```
create or replace TRIGGER RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION."TRG_TRK_KPI_DEFINITION" AFTER UPDATE ON RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.KPI_DEFINITION 
  FOR EACH ROW   
BEGIN
    ----New change
  --IF NOT  :old.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL=:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL THEN
  IF NOT NVL(:old.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,0)=NVL(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,0) THEN
    INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.FIELD_TRACKING  (TABLE_ID, FIELD_NAME,FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE,USER_ID, FIELD_TRACKING_COMMENTS)
    VALUES (:new.KPI_DEF_ID,'Active(Manual)',NVL(to_char(:old.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL),'Y'),NVL(to_char(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL),'Y'),:new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,decode(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,'N','This KPI has been deactivated by System -> Active Alerts','' ));
  END IF;

END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a nested `decode`:

```
decode(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL,'N',
  decode(:new.Last_Updated_By, 115,
    'This KPI has been deactivated by System -> Active Alerts',
    ''),
  '')
```

But it's simpler to use a `case` expression instead:

```
INSERT INTO RATOR_MONITORING_CONFIGURATION.FIELD_TRACKING  (TABLE_ID,
  FIELD_NAME,FIELD_OLD_VALUE,FIELD_NEW_VALUE,USER_ID, FIELD_TRACKING_COMMENTS)
VALUES (:new.KPI_DEF_ID, 'Active(Manual)',
  NVL(to_char(:old.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL),'Y'),
  NVL(to_char(:new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL),'Y'),
  :new.LAST_UPDATED_BY,
  case when :new.KPI_ACTIVE_MANUAL = 'N' AND :new.Last_Updated_By = 115
    then 'This KPI has been deactivated by System -> Active Alerts'
    else '' end
);
```

Though persionally I'd use `null` instead of `''`, and you can omit the `else null` clause as that is the default. Also seems odd that your outer `IF` condition is NVL'ing the flag value to `0`, since it seems to be a character column for `Y`/`N`.

Comment: Ok i replace this  insert with your answer and its saying column not allowed here at the place of Last_Updated_By in case statement

Comment: @rahul - yes, I copied what you'd put without thinking enough. Do you want the old or new value of that column? I've updated the answer to use `:new` as that seems the obvious choice from what you are checking, but you could use `:old` if you prefer.